# Вывод символов Unicode в Си Code Blocks Linux Mint

Tags: linux, c, кодировка, utf-8

Доброго времени суток!
Как выводить символы Unicode в Си. Интересуют символы типа '|', для создания интерфейса у терминале. Linux Mint, работаю в Code Blocks. 
Как вывести все символы Unicode?

P.S. Расширенная ASCII тоже не работает.

Comment: Для создания интерфейса в терминале можно посмотреть также в сторону таких библиотек как [ncurses](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int w=0; w < 0x110000; w++) {
    if(w<128) putchar(w);
    else if(w<2048) { putchar(w>>6 | 0xC0); putchar(w&63 | 0x80); }
    else if(w<1<<16) { putchar(w>>12 | 0xE0); putchar(w>>6 & 63 | 0x80); putchar(w&63 | 0x80);}
    else if(w<1<<21) { putchar(w>>18 | 0xF0); putchar(w>>12 & 63 | 0x80); putchar(w>>6 & 63 | 0x80); putchar(w&63 | 0x80); }
    else if(w<1<<26){ putchar(w>>24 | 0xF8); putchar(w>>18 & 63 | 0x80); putchar(w>>12 & 63 | 0x80); putchar(w>>6 & 63 | 0x80); putchar(w&63 | 0x80); }
    else{ putchar(w>>30 | 0xFC); putchar(w>>24 & 63 | 0x80); putchar(w>>18 & 63 | 0x80); putchar(w>>12 & 63 | 0x80); putchar(w>>6 & 63 | 0x80); putchar(w&63 | 0x80); }
}
```